# What is the difference between 'use' and 'apply'?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> • Farmers_________chemical fertilizers and insecticides in their fields.

In the above sentence two words that comes to my mind one is 'Use' and the other is 'Apply' . Now my question is if I use anyone from these  two words  will be correct ?

And second question is what is the difference between 'use' and 'apply' if one of them is correct?
(Depends on first question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, "in their *field*" has a different meaning from "in their *fields*".

> **[field](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/field)** (n): *a particular branch of study or sphere of activity or interest.*

"Use" is a more generic verb that can be *used* in a wide array of situations, but it's fine in this sentence.

> Farmers **use** chemical fertilizers **in** their fields.

"Apply" is more specific as it means "to put on the surface of", either literally or metaphorically.  Also, the common verb + preposition is "apply *to*":

> Farmers **apply** chemical fertilizers and insecticides **to** their **fields**.

While this is grammatical, it would be more idiomatic to use "spray on", because this is specifically how fertilizers and insecticides are *applied*.

> Farmers **spray** chemical fertilizers and insecticides **on** their fields.

Comment: Glad you cleared that one up. One wonders who is writing these exercises....

Comment: I am sorry it was typo